# had in past perfect confusion

Tags: grammar

I have this sentence: The content of such texts differs from the type of content author X **had** dealt with before such new textual theory came to the scene.

I am assuming past perfect should work here, because of an event prior to an event in history, but when I read it, it doesn't sound correct to me. Do you find that correct grammatically?

Comment: It's not clear what the leading **It** refers to unless it means: **The content of such texts differs from .......etc** But the use of the past perfect to refer to an action prior to a subsequent action is correct.

Comment: I have edited the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the temporal relationships are clear, the past perfect is not required, but it is perfectly acceptable, and I would probably use it.

The only difference in meaning is that if you use the past perfect, you are setting a temporal focus (in the later period of those "such texts"), whereas if you don't you are not setting a temporal focus. If following sentences assume a temporal focus (as they probably would if you were narrating a story), this can be significant; but if they don't (or there isn't any following text) then this difference will have no effect.